# Post Data from Android (simulator) - implementation problems

Tags: java, android, client-server, httpclient

My application generates a UDID and sends it to the server side. However, on the server side the $_POST variable is empty. My php code is working as i have tried it with test data. There is something wrong with the Android code but i cannot figure it out. I am running the app on the emulator.

SecondAct.java --

```
public class SecondAct extends Activity {
private String android_id;

public String getUDID(){
    android_id = Secure.getString(getBaseContext().getContentResolver(), Secure.ANDROID_ID);
    return android_id;
}

public void PostServer(View view){

    ConnectivityManager connMgr = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    NetworkInfo networkInfo = connMgr.getActiveNetworkInfo();
    if(networkInfo != null && networkInfo.isConnected()){
        //send data
        new PostHttp(getUDID()).execute();
    }
    else{
        //display error
    }
}
```

PostHttp.java --

```
public class PostHttp extends AsyncTask<Void,Integer,Void>  {
private String id = null;

PostHttp(String s){
    id = s;
}
protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    //Create the HTTP Post
    HttpParams httpParameters = new BasicHttpParams(); 

    //Setup timeouts -- for later

    HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient(httpParameters);
    HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(webphp);

    try{
    ArrayList<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(2);
    nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("id",id));
    nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("time",time));    
    httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
    HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
    HttpEntity resEntity = response.getEntity();
    String result = EntityUtils.toString(resEntity);

    System.out.println(result);

 } catch (Exception e){
           e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return null;    
}
```

Geo.php --

```
<?
mysql_connect($host, $username, $password);
mysql_select_db($database) or die("Unable to connect to database");
$query = "INSERT INTO UDID (Time, UDID) VALUES (".$_POST['time'].", ".$_POST['id'].");";
$result = mysql_query($query) or die("Unable to execute query");

echo $_POST;
echo $_POST["id"];
?>
```

LogCat --

```
05-25 03:48:07.176: I/System.out(930): string(19) "2014-05-25 03:48:06"
05-25 03:48:07.176: I/System.out(930): string(16) "2bd5d455facd7fa2"
05-25 03:48:07.186: I/System.out(930): array(3) {
05-25 03:48:07.186: I/System.out(930):   ["id"]=>
05-25 03:48:07.186: I/System.out(930):   string(16) "2bd5d455facd7fa2"
05-25 03:48:07.186: I/System.out(930):   ["time"]=>
05-25 03:48:07.186: I/System.out(930):   string(19) "2014-05-25 03:48:06"
05-25 03:48:07.186: I/System.out(930):   ["extra"]=>
05-25 03:48:07.186: I/System.out(930):   string(4) "xxxx"
05-25 03:48:07.196: I/System.out(930): }
05-25 03:48:07.196: I/System.out(930): Array2bd5d455facd7fa2
```

Comment: "i have tried it with test data". How? As soon as possible you should let echo/print your script a response and grab that response in your android code. Just echo the parameters to begin with. Now you put them in a database and only check the validity quering the database. Thats not how one test an upload. Do away with the database first and echo a response.

Comment: i edited the code to echo a response. I get a JSONException. I'm following this code for this entire procedure:
http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2325799

Comment: Do not use json. Just echo($_POST['id']); and so on. Keep it simple. And print out the whole post array. Only two lines of code for that. Where does FirstName and XYZ come in play?

Comment: Show your complete script. Edit the android code not using json.

Comment: Edited. Please see Logcat. The last line is the response.

Comment: So what is the conclusion? You make it very difficult to debug what is going on. For instance in your php script you should echo some decent lines with some text where you tell wich parameter you are going to print/echo. Further your logcat: are all those lines the output of `.println(result)` ? If not print something before and after so we clearly can see what `result` is. But anyhow we can all see that id and time are received ok by the script. Or not?

Comment: All lines are the response. From where do they come else? But as said add more lines to your script.

Comment: Yes the result string is the response and the LogCat show the output of the result string. IF the response is received ok then why is it that the php script show NULL (when i access the php file on browser) when i echo var_dump($_POST["id"])

Comment: "when i access the php file on browser" ? Please elaborate how you exactly do that!

Comment: i mean when i open the address: http://xxx.php

Comment: "open the address"? Please tell exactly what you are doing!!!!!!!!!

Comment: I meant to say that the post request is sent to php file right. The php file on the server has an address say: http://www.example.com/a.php
Opening meant opening this address in the browser

Comment: You still did not exactly tell what you are doing. Is the script you showed all that is in the php file? There is no html with a <form> and <input>'s which display in the browser first? And the user does not have to submit that form? Otherwise if you just open that url in a browser then the browser will POST nothing and will GET nothing. Beacaus how would the browser know which parameters to send?

Comment: Yes that all of the php. My purpose was to store the UDID sent from Android device in the database. I dont think i need HTML for that. I can run the php file to echo what is in the $_POST variables

Comment: You only need the html if you want to test your script from a browser. For the rest you have seen now that android posts your parameters ok. They are received well by your script. So now you can go on with the code where you try to put them in the database as there goes something wrong.

Comment: Yep i just tried that (see my .php). Still the same problem. Database show 0 records

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem here was that the Insert Query was not executing due to a mismatch of data type. The data type in the database originally was `TIME` but when changed to `TIMESTAMP` the `INSERT` was successful.

Answer (score -1):

try this

```
protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        //Create the HTTP Post
        HttpParams httpParameters = new BasicHttpParams(); 

        //Setup timeouts -- for later

        HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient(httpParameters);
        HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(webphp);

        try{
     MultipartEntity entity = new MultipartEntity(HttpMultipartMode.BROWSER_COMPATIBLE);

       entity.addPart"id",id);
       entity.addPart("time",time);    
       httppost.setEntity(entity);
        httpclient.execute(httppost);
        } catch (Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return null;    
    }
```

Comment: How do i convert a string to a ContentBody? Since id and time are strings